# WebRTC Changing Media Streams on the Go

Tags: webrtc

Now since device enumeration is present in chrome, i know i can select a device during "getUserMedia" negotiation. I was also wondering whether i could switch devices during the middle of a call (queue up a local track and switch tracks or do i have to renegotiate the stream)? I am not sure if this is something that is still blocked or now is "allowable"

I have tried to make a new track, but i can't figure out how to switch the track on the go. I know this was previously impossible, but was wondering now if it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox, you can use the RTPSender object to call `replaceTrack()` to replace a track on the fly (with no renegotiation).  This should eventually be supported by other browsers as part of the spec.

Without `replaceTrack()`, you can remove the old stream, add a new one, deal with onnegotiationnedded, and let the client process the change in streams.

See the `replaceTrack()` test in the Mozilla source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpSender/replaceTrack

Answer (score 1):

Even i have the same requirement. I have to record the video using MediaRecorder. For this I am using navigator.getUserMedia with constraints of audio and video. You can pass the video or audio tracks dynamically by getting the available devices from navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() and attaching the respective device to constraints and calling navigator.getUserMedia with new constraints again. The point to be noted when doing this is, you have to kill the existing tracks using track.stop() method.

You can see my example here.

[StreamTrack's readyState is getting changed to ended, just before playing the stream (MediaStream - MediaStreamTrack - WebRTC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44569562/streamtracks-readystate-is-getting-changed-to-ended-just-before-playing-the-st)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling getUserMedia() when you want to change to a different device?

There's an applyConstraints() method in the Media Capture and Streams spec that makes it possible to change constraints on the fly, but it hasn't been implemented yet:

[dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html#the-model-sources-sinks-constraints-and-states](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html#the-model-sources-sinks-constraints-and-states)
[dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html#methods-1](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html#methods-1)

Comment: Do you have an idea of when `applyConstraints()` (and more generally the [Constrainable Pattern](http://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/getusermedia.html#constrainable-interface) will be implemented by Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox? It would make changing constraints on-the-fly that much easier, instead of having to call `navigator.getUserMedia()` with new constraints, and inflicting the pain on the end user of having to re-allow, every time.

Comment: As per my knowledge, applyConstraints() is used only to change few constraints of the same track (like change of dimensions, frameRate, echoCancellation and so on). I think we cannot change the audio and video tracks completely with applyConstraints coz applyConstraints is the method if MediaTrack (which is the track being used here) and these will be applied to existing track.