# StreamTrack's readyState is getting changed to ended, just before playing the stream (MediaStream - MediaStreamTrack - WebRTC)

Tags: webrtc, mediastream

The jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/kalyansai99/mm1b74uy/22/) contains code where the user can toggle between front and back camera of the mobile.

In few mobiles its working fine (Moto g5 plus, Moto E3 and so on - Chrome Browser) and in few mobiles (Mi Redimi Note 4 - Chrome Browser) when I am switching to back camera, initially the stream is loading with a track of "readyState" as "live". But when i am about to play the stream in video player, the "readyState" is getting changed to "ended" and black screen is been shown on the video tag.

Not sure whats happening. Any clues?

JSFiddle Code

```js
var player = document.getElementById('player');
var flipBtn = document.getElementById('flipBtn');
var deviceIdMap = {};
var front;

var constraints = {
    audio: false,
    video: {
        frameRate: 1000
    }
};

var gotDevices = function (deviceList) {
    var length = deviceList.length;
    console.log(deviceList);
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var deviceInfo = deviceList[i];
        if (deviceInfo.kind === 'videoinput') {
            if (deviceInfo.label.indexOf('front') !== -1) {
                deviceIdMap.front = deviceInfo.deviceId;
            } else if (deviceInfo.label.indexOf('back') !== -1) {
                deviceIdMap.back = deviceInfo.deviceId;
            }
        }
    }
    if (deviceIdMap.front) {
        constraints.video.deviceId = {exact: deviceIdMap.front};
        front = true;
    } else if (deviceIdMap.back) {
        constraints.video.deviceId = {exact: deviceIdMap.back};
        front = false;
    }
    console.log('deviceIdMap - ', deviceIdMap);
};

var handleError = function (error) {
    console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);
};

function handleSuccess(stream) {
    window.stream = stream;
    // this is a video track as there is no audio track
    console.log("Track - ", window.stream.getTracks()[0]);
    console.log('Ready State - ', window.stream.getTracks()[0].readyState);
    if (window.URL) {
        player.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    } else {
        player.src = stream;
    }
    player.onloadedmetadata = function (e) {
      console.log('Ready State - 3', window.stream.getTracks()[0].readyState);
        player.play();
        console.log('Ready State - 4', window.stream.getTracks()[0].readyState);
    }
    console.log('Ready State - 2', window.stream.getTracks()[0].readyState);
}

navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(gotDevices).catch(handleError);

flipBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  if (window.stream) {
      window.stream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
        track.stop();
      });
    }
   if (front) {
      constraints.video.deviceId = {exact: deviceIdMap.back};
    } else {
      constraints.video.deviceId = {exact: deviceIdMap.front};
    }
   front = !front;
   navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, handleSuccess, handleError);
}, false);

console.log(constraints);
navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, handleSuccess, handleError);
```

```css
#player {
  width: 320px;
}

#flipBtn {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<video id="player" autoplay></video>

<div>
  <button id="flipBtn">
      Flip Camera
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Replace `track.stop()` to `track.enabled=false` and when adding track to the stream, enable it back using `track.enabled=true`

The `MediaStream.readyState` property is changed to "ended" when we stop the track and can never be used again. Therefore its not wise to use stop. For more reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/readyState

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/stop