# How change streams in peerJS

Tags: javascript, angular, peerjs

I use **peerJs**.
I need to switch the stream from the camera to the screen share during the broadcast. Can I change the streams?

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

With `peerjs` we can **change/switch** both **video and audio tracks** as below

`peer.call('other-id',stream)` on success returns an object containing `peerConnection` as below

```
let call = peer.call('other-id',stream)
call.peerConnection //object
```

this `peerConnection` object contains a function `getSenders()` which when executed returns an `array` of two tracks first `one is audio second is video`

then you can call `replaceTrack(newTrack)` as below am replacing audio track

```
call.peerConnection.getSenders()[0].replaceTrack(newTrack)
```

Comment: how to get new track? like if I want to get front side camera stream then how can I get it as newTrack please help me I am stuck here for long time

Answer (score 1):

Changing stream is possible by using [replaceTrack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpSender/replaceTrack).

maybe [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49645282/12129650) help

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I replace from camera to screen sharing in PeerJS with ReactJS.

```
function replaceStream() {
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(device).then((stream) => {
  callSate.peerConnection.getSenders().forEach((sender) => {
    if(sender.track.kind === "audio" && stream.getAudioTracks().length > 0){
      sender.replaceTrack(stream.getAudioTracks()[0]);
  }
    if (sender.track.kind === "video" && stream.getVideoTracks().length > 0) {
      sender.replaceTrack(stream.getVideoTracks()[0]);
    }
  });
  videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
  videoRef.current.play();
});
```

}

1. Here callSate is state/variable holds the value of call object which is returned when we make call or answer call of peer.
2. You can change getDisplayMedia to getUserMedia according to your need.
3. VideoRef holds the reference to video displayed on frontend.